# Serial Communication stops working when loop is started

Tags: vb.net

I have problem with serial data communication if I started a loop it is not updating the data from my weighing scale. I can't figure out how to continue the communication as well as to run the loop. The logic of my code will be in the loop so I could check the value from my integer and compare it to the data from serial data (Weighing Scale)

```
Private Sub conWeight_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles conWeight.DataReceived

receivedText(conWeight.ReadExisting())

End Sub


Private Sub receivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.lblWeight.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf receivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        Dim reverseString As String = [text]
        Dim revString As String = StrReverse(reverseString)
        Dim clean As String
        clean = revString.Replace("=", "")
        Me.lblWeight.Text = clean 'append text
    End If
End Sub

'this is part with loop

 If binWeight = 0 Then
            targetweight = CInt(txtbSilo1.Text) + CInt(txtbSilo2.Text) + CInt(txtbSilo3.Text) + CInt(txtbSilo4.Text)
            If CInt(txtbSilo1.Text) > 0 Then
                currentWeight = CInt(txtbSilo1.Text)
                frmAutomaticControl.conControl.Open()
                frmAutomaticControl.conControl.Write("motr1")
                frmAutomaticControl.conControl.Close()
                MsgBox("check")
                Do
                    If binWeight >= currentWeight Then
                        frmAutomaticControl.conControl.Open()
                        frmAutomaticControl.conControl.Write("moto1")
                        frmAutomaticControl.conControl.Close()
                        Exit Do
                    End If

                Loop
            Else

            End If
            BunifuFlatButton1.Enabled = True
        Else
            MsgBox("Empty The Bin")
        End If
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a timer to repeatedly call the code you currently have inside the loop. You then can remove the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a couple of ideas.
1. Throw that part of the code into a background worker.
2. Cheese it and throw in an application.doevents.
3. Create a global variable that'll capture the output of each iteration of your loop that'll then feed it where it needs to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just one line of code is all you need. In your loop put this above everything else.

```
Application.DoEvents()
```